# JQuery : call a function with a String Variable

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, call, handler

I'm creating a JQuery plugin which takes in parameter a String : handler.

Depending on that, my plugin will be launched.
Example if : "handler = submit"

In my plugin I'll call :

```
$("form").submit(function() {
// Code inside
});
```

With handler = "focusOut"

```
$("form").submit(function() {
// Code inside
});
```

I've tried :

```
 $("form").this[handler](function()
 $("form").window[handler](function()
```

But no results.
Any idea ?
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an event

```
var handler = 'submit';

$("form").on(handler, function() {

});
```

If it's a jQuery method

```
var handler = 'hide';

$('#element')[handler]();
```

or with a callback

```
var handler = 'fadeIn';

$('form')[handler](function() {

});
```

`$()` returns an object, so you can use either dot or bracket notation to reference the method, which would be a property of the object etc. so just replace the dot notation with the appropriate bracket notation instead.

If it's an event, you're better of using `on()`, but you could also use bracket notation to reference the method directly, like above.